# AuthenticationManagerBuilder in java

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jwt

I trying to set up an authentication with angular/ Java. for the java part I have all the filters working so I only can go to /login without a token. The only thing that is not working is checking users passwords and handing out Tokens for others than the inMemoryAuthentication for now this are 1 user and 1 admin. How can I link my Users entity (i have users server dao controller etc...) so I can give tokens to all my users in the database after checking there passwords.

this is what I have now :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll() 
                                                                                    
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER").and().withUser("admin")
                .password("{noop}password").roles("ADMIN");


//// here I want to add all my users from the database


    }
}
```

Comment: well if you are starting out, then these articles can be of great help https://itnext.io/@marcusdacoregio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JDBCAuthentication Builder to store and retrieve all the users from DB.

First define the schema to be used `schema.sql` -

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
);
  
CREATE TABLE authorities (
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  authority VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username)
);
 
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_auth_username
  on authorities (username,authority);
```

Then some sample data `data.sql` -

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, enabled)
  values ('user',
    '$2a$10$8.UnVuG9HHgffUDAlk8qfOuVGkqRzgVymGe07xd00DMxs.AQubh4a',
    1);
 
INSERT INTO authorities (username, authority)
  values ('user', 'ROLE_USER');
```

Update your application properties to point to the correct DB -

```
# MySQL
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
#spring.datasource.username=dbuser
#spring.datasource.password=dbpass
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Also tell hibernate that your are not using default schema, so you should disable the `ddl-auto` property

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Then you can update your security configuration as follows -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    //DataSource connection to your DB
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll() 
                                                                                    
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // cualquier otra peticion requiere autenticacion
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       //Telling spring to use DB based authentication.
       auth.jdbcAuthentication()
           .dataSource(dataSource);

    }
}
```

Comment: great it worked.. in postman. I can now check paswords and give tokens. Still having a 403 in Angular.

Comment: and got it working in Angular aswell now was a CORS issue